# Turtlebot Navigation Error in Fuerte and 12.04

Tags: turtlebot, ros-fuerte

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to run the navigation demo in Fuerte and 12.04 Precise, after completely successfully running the SLAM GMAP demo, and I get the following rolling list of errors which goes on forever.  Does anyone know what might be wrong?

```
rscan/CloudThrottle openni_manager cloud_in:=/camera/depth/points cloud_out:=cloud_throttled __name:=pointcloud_throttle __log:=/home/turtlebot/.ros/log/661c8e88-fcf9-11e1-8620-485d607f80f5/pointcloud_throttle-4.log].
log file: /home/turtlebot/.ros/log/661c8e88-fcf9-11e1-8620-485d607f80f5/pointcloud_throttle-4*.log
respawning...
[pointcloud_throttle-4] restarting process
process[kinect_laser_narrow-6]: started with pid [8744]
Exception AttributeError: AttributeError("'_DummyThread' object has no attribute '_Thread__block'",) in <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.pyc'> ignored
process[pointcloud_throttle-4]: started with pid [8746]
[openni_launch-3] process has died [pid 8605, exit code 255, cmd /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/nodelet_core/nodelet/bin/nodelet load openni_camera/OpenNINodelet openni_manager __name:=openni_launch __log:=/home/turtlebot/.ros/log/661c8e88-fcf9-11e1-8620-485d607f80f5/openni_launch-3.log].
log file: /home/turtlebot/.ros/log/661c8e88-fcf9-11e1-8620-485d607f80f5/openni_launch-3*.log
respawning...
[openni_launch-3] restarting process
Exception AttributeError: AttributeError("'_DummyThread' object has no attribute '_Thread__block'",) in <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.pyc'> ignored
process[openni_launch-3]: started with pid [8772]
[kinect_laser-5] process has died [pid 8632, exit code 255, cmd /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/nodelet_core/nodelet/bin/nodelet load pointcloud_to_laserscan/CloudToScan openni_manager cloud:=/cloud_throttled __name:=kinect_laser __log:=/home/turtlebot/.ros/log/661c8e88-fcf9-11e1-8620-485d607f80f5/kinect_laser-5.log].
log file: /home/turtlebot/.ros/log/661c8e88-fcf9-11e1-8620-485d607f80f5/kinect_laser-5*.log
respawning...
[kinect_laser_narrow-6] process has died [pid 8635, exit code 255, cmd /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/nodelet_core/nodelet/bin/nodelet load pointcloud_to_laserscan/CloudToScan openni_manager cloud:=/cloud_throttled scan:=/narrow_scan __name:=kinect_laser_narrow __log:=/home/turtlebot/.ros/log/661c8e88-fcf9-11e1-8620-485d607f80f5/kinect_laser_narrow-6.log].
log file: /home/turtlebot/.ros/log/661c8e88-fcf9-11e1-8620-485d607f80f5/kinect_laser_narrow-6*.log
respawning...
[kinect_laser-5] restarting process
Exception AttributeError: AttributeError("'_DummyThread' object has no attribute '_Thread__block'",) in <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.pyc'> ignored
process[kinect_laser-5]: started with pid [8824]
[kinect_laser_narrow-6] restarting process
Exception AttributeError: AttributeError("'_DummyThread' object has no attribute '_Thread__block'",) in <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.pyc'> ignored
process[kinect_laser_narrow-6]: started with pid [8829]
[ INFO] [1347468668.184002927]: Sim period is set to 0.20
[openni_launch-3] process has died [pid 8693, exit code 255, cmd /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/nodelet_core/nodelet/bin/nodelet load openni_camera/OpenNINodelet openni_manager __name:=openni_launch __log:=/home/turtlebot/.ros/log/661c8e88-fcf9-11e1-8620-485d607f80f5/openni_launch-3.log].
log file: /home/turtlebot/.ros/log/661c8e88-fcf9-11e1-8620-485d607f80f5/openni_launch-3*.log
respawning...
[openni_launch-3] restarting process
Exception AttributeError: AttributeError("'_DummyThread' object has no attribute '_Thread__block'",) in <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.pyc'> ignored
process[openni_launch-3]: started with pid [8884]
[pointcloud_throttle-4] process has died [pid 8643, exit code 255, cmd /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/nodelet_core/nodelet/bin/nodelet load pointcloud_to_laserscan/CloudThrottle openni_manager cloud_in:=/camera/depth/points cloud_out:=cloud_throttled __name:=pointcloud_throttle __log:=/home/turtlebot/.ros/log/661c8e88-fcf9-11e1-8620-485d607f80f5/pointcloud_throttle-4.log].
log file: /home/turtlebot/.ros/log/661c8e88-fcf9-11e1-8620-485d607f80f5/pointcloud_throttle-4*.log
respawning...
[kinect_laser-5] process has died [pid 8741, exit code 255, cmd /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/nodelet_core/nodelet/bin/nodelet load pointcloud_to_laserscan/CloudToScan openni_manager cloud:=/cloud_throttled __name:=kinect_laser __log:=/home/turtlebot/.ros/log/661c8e88-fcf9-11e1-8620-485d607f80f5/kinect_laser-5.log].
log file: /home/turtlebot/.ros/log/661c8e88-fcf9-11e1-8620-485d607f80f5/kinect_laser-5*.log
respawning...
[kinect_laser_narrow-6] process has died [pid 8744, exit code 255, cmd /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/nodelet_core/nodelet/bin/nodelet load pointcloud_to_laserscan/CloudToScan openni_manager cloud:=/cloud_throttled scan:=/narrow_scan __name:=kinect_laser_narrow __log:=/home/turtlebot/.ros/log/661c8e88-fcf9-11e1-8620-485d607f80f5/kinect_laser_narrow-6.log].
log file: /home/turtlebot/.ros/log/661c8e88-fcf9-11e1-8620-485d607f80f5/kinect_laser_narrow-6*.log
respawning...
[pointcloud_throttle-4] restarting process
Exception AttributeError: AttributeError("'_DummyThread' object has no attribute '_Thread__block'",) in <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.pyc'> ignored
process[pointcloud_throttle-4]: started with pid [8911]
[kinect_laser-5] restarting process
Exception AttributeError: AttributeError("'_DummyThread' object has no attribute '_Thread__block'",) in <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.pyc'> ignored
process[kinect_laser-5]: started with pid [8915]
[kinect_laser_narrow-6] restarting process
Exception AttributeError: AttributeError("'_DummyThread' object has no attribute '_Thread__block'",) in <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.pyc'> ignored
process[kinect_laser_narrow-6]: started with pid [8918]
[openni_launch-3] process has died [pid 8772, exit code 255, cmd /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/nodelet_core/nodelet/bin/nodelet load openni_camera/OpenNINodelet openni_manager __name:=openni_launch __log:=/home/turtlebot/.ros/log/661c8e88-fcf9-11e1-8620-485d607f80f5/openni_launch-3.log].
log file: /home/turtlebot/.ros/log/661c8e88-fcf9-11e1-8620-485d607f80f5/openni_launch-3*.log
respawning...
[openni_launch-3] restarting process
Exception AttributeError: AttributeError("'_DummyThread' object has no attribute '_Thread__block'",) in <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.pyc'> ignored
process[openni_launch-3]: started with pid [8972]
[pointcloud_throttle-4] process has died [pid 8746, exit code 255, cmd /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/nodelet_core/nodelet/bin/nodelet load pointcloud_to_laserscan/CloudThrottle openni_manager cloud_in:=/camera/depth/points cloud_out:=cloud_throttled __name:=pointcloud_throttle __log:=/home/turtlebot/.ros/log/661c8e88-fcf9-11e1-8620-485d607f80f5/pointcloud_throttle-4.log].
log file: /home/turtlebot/.ros/log/661c8e88-fcf9-11e1-8620-485d607f80f5/pointcloud_throttle-4*.log
respawning...
[kinect_laser-5] process has died [pid 8824, exit code 255, cmd /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/nodelet_core/nodelet/bin/nodelet load pointcloud_to_laserscan/CloudToScan openni_manager cloud:=/cloud_throttled __name:=kinect_laser __log:=/home/turtlebot/.ros/log/661c8e88-fcf9-11e1-8620-485d607f80f5/kinect_laser-5.log].
log file: /home/turtlebot/.ros/log/661c8e88-fcf9-11e1-8620-485d607f80f5/kinect_laser-5*.log
respawning...
[kinect_laser_narrow-6] process has died [pid 8829, exit code 255, cmd /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/nodelet_core/nodelet/bin/nodelet load pointcloud_to_laserscan/CloudToScan openni_manager cloud:=/cloud_throttled scan:=/narrow_scan __name:=kinect_laser_narrow __log:=/home/turtlebot/.ros/log/661c8e88-fcf9-11e1-8620-485d607f80f5/kinect_laser_narrow-6.log].
log file: /home/turtlebot/.ros/log/661c8e88-fcf9-11e1-8620-485d607f80f5/kinect_laser_narrow-6*.log
respawning...
[pointcloud_throttle-4] restarting process
Exception AttributeError: AttributeError("'_DummyThread' object has no attribute '_Thread__block'",) in <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.pyc'> ignored
process[pointcloud_throttle-4]: started with pid [9000]
[kinect_laser-5] restarting process
Exception AttributeError: AttributeError("'_DummyThread' object has no attribute '_Thread__block'",) in <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.pyc'> ignored
process[kinect_laser-5]: started with pid [9007]
[kinect_laser_narrow-6] restarting process
Exception AttributeError: AttributeError("'_DummyThread' object has no attribute '_Thread__block'",) in <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.pyc'> ignored
process[kinect_laser_narrow-6]: started with pid [9011]
[openni_launch-3] process has died [pid 8884, exit code 255, cmd /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/nodelet_core/nodelet/bin/nodelet load openni_camera/OpenNINodelet openni_manager __name:=openni_launch __log:=/home/turtlebot/.ros/log/661c8e88-fcf9-11e1-8620-485d607f80f5/openni_launch-3.log].
log file: /home/turtlebot/.ros/log/661c8e88-fcf9-11e1-8620-485d607f80f5/openni_launch-3*.log
respawning...
[openni_launch-3] restarting process
Exception AttributeError: AttributeError("'_DummyThread' object has no attribute '_Thread__block'",) in <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.pyc'> ignored
process[openni_launch-3]: started with pid [9074]
[kinect_laser-5] process has died [pid 8915, exit code 255, cmd /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/nodelet_core/nodelet/bin/nodelet load pointcloud_to_laserscan/CloudToScan openni_manager cloud:=/cloud_throttled __name:=kinect_laser __log:=/home/turtlebot/.ros/log/661c8e88-fcf9-11e1-8620-485d607f80f5/kinect_laser-5.log].
log file: /home/turtlebot/.ros/log/661c8e88-fcf9-11e1-8620-485d607f80f5/kinect_laser-5*.log
respawning...
[kinect_laser-5] restarting process
Exception AttributeError: AttributeError("'_DummyThread' object has no attribute '_Thread__block'",) in <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.pyc'> ignored
process[kinect_laser-5]: started with pid [9102]
[pointcloud_throttle-4] process has died [pid 8911, exit code 255, cmd /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/nodelet_core/nodelet/bin/nodelet load pointcloud_to_laserscan/CloudThrottle openni_manager cloud_in:=/camera/depth/points cloud_out:=cloud_throttled __name:=pointcloud_throttle __log:=/home/turtlebot/.ros/log/661c8e88-fcf9-11e1-8620-485d607f80f5/pointcloud_throttle-4.log].
log file: /home/turtlebot/.ros/log/661c8e88-fcf9-11e1-8620-485d607f80f5/pointcloud_throttle-4*.log
respawning...
[kinect_laser_narrow-6] process has died [pid 8918, exit code 255, cmd /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/nodelet_core/nodelet/bin/nodelet load pointcloud_to_laserscan/CloudToScan openni_manager cloud:=/cloud_throttled scan:=/narrow_scan __name:=kinect_laser_narrow __log:=/home/turtlebot/.ros/log/661c8e88-fcf9-11e1-8620-485d607f80f5/kinect_laser_narrow-6.log].
log file: /home/turtlebot/.ros/log/661c8e88-fcf9-11e1-8620-485d607f80f5/kinect_laser_narrow-6*.log
respawning...
[pointcloud_throttle-4] restarting process
Exception AttributeError: AttributeError("'_DummyThread' object has no attribute '_Thread__block'",) in <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.pyc'> ignored
process[pointcloud_throttle-4]: started with pid [9136]
[kinect_laser_narrow-6] restarting process
Exception AttributeError: AttributeError("'_DummyThread' object has no attribute '_Thread__block'",) in <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.pyc'> ignored
process[kinect_laser_narrow-6]: started with pid [9139]
[openni_launch-3] process has died [pid 8972, exit code 255, cmd /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/nodelet_core/nodelet/bin/nodelet load openni_camera/OpenNINodelet openni_manager __name:=openni_launch __log:=/home/turtlebot/.ros/log/661c8e88-fcf9-11e1-8620-485d607f80f5/openni_launch-3.log].
log file: /home/turtlebot/.ros/log/661c8e88-fcf9-11e1-8620-485d607f80f5/openni_launch-3*.log
respawning...
[openni_launch-3] restarting process
Exception AttributeError: AttributeError("'_DummyThread' object has no attribute '_Thread__block'",) in <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.pyc'> ignored
process[openni_launch-3]: started with pid [9168]
[kinect_laser-5] process has died [pid 9007, exit code 255, cmd /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/nodelet_core/nodelet/bin/nodelet load pointcloud_to_laserscan/CloudToScan openni_manager cloud:=/cloud_throttled __name:=kinect_laser __log:=/home/turtlebot/.ros/log/661c8e88-fcf9-11e1-8620-485d607f80f5/kinect_laser-5.log].
log file: /home/turtlebot/.ros/log/661c8e88-fcf9-11e1-8620-485d607f80f5/kinect_laser-5*.log
respawning...
[kinect_laser-5] restarting process
Exception AttributeError: AttributeError("'_DummyThread' object has no attribute '_Thread__block'",) in <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.pyc'> ignored
process[kinect_laser-5]: started with pid [9199]
[pointcloud_throttle-4] process has died [pid 9000, exit code 255, cmd /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/nodelet_core/nodelet/bin/nodelet load pointcloud_to_laserscan/CloudThrottle openni_manager cloud_in:=/camera/depth/points cloud_out:=cloud_throttled __name:=pointcloud_throttle __log:=/home/turtlebot/.ros/log/661c8e88-fcf9-11e1-8620-485d607f80f5/pointcloud_throttle-4.log].
log file: /home/turtlebot/.ros/log/661c8e88-fcf9-11e1-8620-485d607f80f5/pointcloud_throttle-4*.log
respawning...
[kinect_laser_narrow-6] process has died [pid 9011, exit code 255, cmd /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/nodelet_core/nodelet/bin/nodelet load pointcloud_to_laserscan/CloudToScan openni_manager cloud:=/cloud_throttled scan:=/narrow_scan __name:=kinect_laser_narrow __log:=/home/turtlebot/.ros/log/661c8e88-fcf9-11e1-8620-485d607f80f5/kinect_laser_narrow-6.log].
log file: /home/turtlebot/.ros/log/661c8e88-fcf9-11e1-8620-485d607f80f5/kinect_laser_narrow-6*.log
respawning...
[pointcloud_throttle-4] restarting process
Exception AttributeError: AttributeError("'_DummyThread' object has no attribute '_Thread__block'",) in <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.pyc'> ignored
process[pointcloud_throttle-4]: started with pid [9228]
[kinect_laser_narrow-6] restarting process
Exception AttributeError: AttributeError("'_DummyThread' object has no attribute '_Thread__block'",) in <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.pyc'> ignored
process[kinect_laser_narrow-6]: started with pid [9231]
[openni_launch-3] process has died [pid 9074, exit code 255, cmd /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/nodelet_core/nodelet/bin/nodelet load openni_camera/OpenNINodelet openni_manager __name:=openni_launch __log:=/home/turtlebot/.ros/log/661c8e88-fcf9-11e1-8620-485d607f80f5/openni_launch-3.log].
log file: /home/turtlebot/.ros/log/661c8e88-fcf9-11e1-8620-485d607f80f5/openni_launch-3*.log
respawning...
[openni_launch-3] restarting process
Exception AttributeError: AttributeError("'_DummyThread' object has no attribute '_Thread__block'",) in <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.pyc'> ignored
process[openni_launch-3]: started with pid [9268]
[kinect_laser-5] process has died [pid 9102, exit code 255, cmd /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/nodelet_core/nodelet/bin/nodelet load pointcloud_to_laserscan/CloudToScan openni_manager cloud:=/cloud_throttled __name:=kinect_laser __log:=/home/turtlebot/.ros/log/661c8e88-fcf9-11e1-8620-485d607f80f5/kinect_laser-5.log].
log file: /home/turtlebot/.ros/log/661c8e88-fcf9-11e1-8620-485d607f80f5/kinect_laser-5*.log
respawning...
[kinect_laser-5] restarting process
Exception AttributeError: AttributeError("'_DummyThread' object has no attribute '_Thread__block'",) in <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.pyc'> ignored
process[kinect_laser-5]: started with pid [9300]
[pointcloud_throttle-4] process has died [pid 9136, exit code 255, cmd /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/nodelet_core/nodelet/bin/nodelet load pointcloud_to_laserscan/CloudThrottle openni_manager cloud_in:=/camera/depth/points cloud_out:=cloud_throttled __name:=pointcloud_throttle __log:=/home/turtlebot/.ros/log/661c8e88-fcf9-11e1-8620-485d607f80f5/pointcloud_throttle-4.log].
log file: /home/turtlebot/.ros/log/661c8e88-fcf9-11e1-8620-485d607f80f5/pointcloud_throttle-4*.log
respawning...
[kinect_laser_narrow-6] process has died [pid 9139, exit code 255, cmd /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/nodelet_core/nodelet/bin/nodelet load pointcloud_to_laserscan/CloudToScan openni_manager cloud:=/cloud_throttled scan:=/narrow_scan __name:=kinect_laser_narrow __log:=/home/turtlebot/.ros/log/661c8e88-fcf9-11e1-8620-485d607f80f5/kinect_laser_narrow-6.log].
log file: /home/turtlebot/.ros/log/661c8e88-fcf9-11e1-8620-485d607f80f5/kinect_laser_narrow-6*.log
respawning...
[pointcloud_throttle-4] restarting process
Exception AttributeError: AttributeError("'_DummyThread' object has no attribute '_Thread__block'",) in <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.pyc'> ignored
process[pointcloud_throttle-4]: started with pid [9329]
[kinect_laser_narrow-6] restarting process
Exception AttributeError: AttributeError("'_DummyThread' object has no attribute '_Thread__block'",) in <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.pyc'> ignored
process[kinect_laser_narrow-6]: started with pid [9335]
[openni_launch-3] process has died [pid 9168, exit code 255, cmd /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/nodelet_core/nodelet/bin/nodelet load openni_camera/OpenNINodelet openni_manager __name:=openni_launch __log:=/home/turtlebot/.ros/log/661c8e88-fcf9-11e1-8620-485d607f80f5/openni_launch-3.log].
log file: /home/turtlebot/.ros/log/661c8e88-fcf9-11e1-8620-485d607f80f5/openni_launch-3*.log
respawning...
[openni_launch-3] restarting process
Exception AttributeError: AttributeError("'_DummyThread' object has no attribute '_Thread__block'",) in <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.pyc'> ignored
process[openni_launch-3]: started with pid [9362]
[kinect_laser-5] process has died [pid 9199, exit code 255, cmd /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/nodelet_core/nodelet/bin/nodelet load pointcloud_to_laserscan/CloudToScan openni_manager cloud:=/cloud_throttled __name:=kinect_laser __log:=/home/turtlebot/.ros/log/661c8e88-fcf9-11e1-8620-485d607f80f5/kinect_laser-5.log].
log file: /home/turtlebot/.ros/log/661c8e88-fcf9-11e1-8620-485d607f80f5/kinect_laser-5*.log
respawning...
[kinect_laser-5] restarting process
Exception AttributeError: AttributeError("'_DummyThread' object has no attribute '_Thread__block'",) in <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.pyc'> ignored
process[kinect_laser-5]: started with pid [9387]
[pointcloud_throttle-4] process has died [pid 9228, exit code 255, cmd /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/nodelet_core/nodelet/bin/nodelet load pointcloud_to_laserscan/CloudThrottle openni_manager cloud_in:=/camera/depth/points cloud_out:=cloud_throttled __name:=pointcloud_throttle __log:=/home/turtlebot/.ros/log/661c8e88-fcf9-11e1-8620-485d607f80f5/pointcloud_throttle-4.log].
log file: /home/turtlebot/.ros/log/661c8e88-fcf9-11e1-8620-485d607f80f5/pointcloud_throttle-4*.log
respawning...
[pointcloud_throttle-4] restarting process
Exception AttributeError: AttributeError("'_DummyThread' object has no attribute '_Thread__block'",) in <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.pyc'> ignored
process[pointcloud_throttle-4]: started with pid [9417]
[kinect_laser_narrow-6] process has died [pid 9231, exit code 255, cmd /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/nodelet_core/nodelet/bin/nodelet load pointcloud_to_laserscan/CloudToScan openni_manager cloud:=/cloud_throttled scan:=/narrow_scan __name:=kinect_laser_narrow __log:=/home/turtlebot/.ros/log/661c8e88-fcf9-11e1-8620-485d607f80f5/kinect_laser_narrow-6.log].
log file: /home/turtlebot/.ros/log/661c8e88-fcf9-11e1-8620-485d607f80f5/kinect_laser_narrow-6*.log
respawning...
[kinect_laser_narrow-6] restarting process
Exception AttributeError: AttributeError("'_DummyThread' object has no attribute '_Thread__block'",) in <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.pyc'> ignored
process[kinect_laser_narrow-6]: started with pid [9446]
[openni_launch-3] process has died [pid 9268, exit code 255, cmd /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/nodelet_core/nodelet/bin/nodelet load openni_camera/OpenNINodelet openni_manager __name:=openni_launch __log:=/home/turtlebot/.ros/log/661c8e88-fcf9-11e1-8620-485d607f80f5/openni_launch-3.log].
log file: /home/turtlebot/.ros/log/661c8e88-fcf9-11e1-8620-485d607f80f5/openni_launch-3*.log
respawning...
[openni_launch-3] restarting process
Exception AttributeError: AttributeError("'_DummyThread' object has no attribute '_Thread__block'",) in <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.pyc'> ignored
process[openni_launch-3]: started with pid [9447]
[kinect_laser-5] process has died [pid 9300, exit code 255, cmd /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/nodelet_core/nodelet/bin/nodelet load pointcloud_to_laserscan/CloudToScan openni_manager cloud:=/cloud_throttled __name:=kinect_laser __log:=/home/turtlebot/.ros/log/661c8e88-fcf9-11e1-8620-485d607f80f5/kinect_laser-5.log].
log file: /home/turtlebot/.ros/log/661c8e88-fcf9-11e1-8620-485d607f80f5/kinect_laser-5*.log
respawning...
[kinect_laser-5] restarting process
Exception AttributeError: AttributeError("'_DummyThread' object has no attribute '_Thread__block'",) in <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.pyc'> ignored
process[kinect_laser-5]: started with pid [9475]
[pointcloud_throttle-4] process has died [pid 9329, exit code 255, cmd /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/nodelet_core/nodelet/bin/nodelet load pointcloud_to_laserscan/CloudThrottle openni_manager cloud_in:=/camera/depth/points cloud_out:=cloud_throttled __name:=pointcloud_throttle __log:=/home/turtlebot/.ros/log/661c8e88-fcf9-11e1-8620-485d607f80f5/pointcloud_throttle-4.log].
log file: /home/turtlebot/.ros/log/661c8e88-fcf9-11e1-8620-485d607f80f5/pointcloud_throttle-4*.log
respawning...
[pointcloud_throttle-4] restarting process
Exception AttributeError: AttributeError("'_DummyThread' object has no attribute '_Thread__block'",) in <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.pyc'> ignored
process[pointcloud_throttle-4]: started with pid [9497]
^C[kinect_laser_narrow-6] process has died [pid 9335, exit code 255, cmd /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/nodelet_core/nodelet/bin/nodelet load pointcloud_to_laserscan/CloudToScan openni_manager cloud:=/cloud_throttled scan:=/narrow_scan __name:=kinect_laser_narrow __log:=/home/turtlebot/.ros/log/661c8e88-fcf9-11e1-8620-485d607f80f5/kinect_laser_narrow-6.log].
log file: /home/turtlebot/.ros/log/661c8e88-fcf9-11e1-8620-485d607f80f5/kinect_laser_narrow-6*.log
respawning...
[openni_launch-3] process has died [pid 9362, exit code 255, cmd /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/nodelet_core/nodelet/bin/nodelet load openni_camera/OpenNINodelet openni_manager __name:=openni_launch __log:=/home/turtlebot/.ros/log/661c8e88-fcf9-11e1-8620-485d607f80f5/openni_launch-3.log].
log file: /home/turtlebot/.ros/log/661c8e88-fcf9-11e1-8620-485d607f80f5/openni_launch-3*.log
respawning...
[openni_launch-3] restarting process
Exception AttributeError: AttributeError("'_DummyThread' object has no attribute '_Thread__block'",) in <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.pyc'> ignored
process[openni_launch-3]: started with pid [9535]
[move_base-9] killing on exit
[ERROR] [1347468671.038918358]: [registerSubscriber] Failed to contact master at [localhost:11311].  Retrying...
[amcl-8] killing on exit
[map_server-7] killing on exit
[kinect_laser_narrow-6] killing on exit
 [kinect_laser-5] killing on exit
[kinect_laser-5] process has died [pid 9387, exit code 255, cmd /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/nodelet_core/nodelet/bin/nodelet load pointcloud_to_laserscan/CloudToScan openni_manager cloud:=/cloud_throttled __name:=kinect_laser __log:=/home/turtlebot/.ros/log/661c8e88-fcf9-11e1-8620-485d607f80f5/kinect_laser-5.log].
log file: /home/turtlebot/.ros/log/661c8e88-fcf9-11e1-8620-485d607f80f5/kinect_laser-5*.log
respawning...
[kinect_laser-5] restarting process
 [openni_manager-2] killing on exit
[openni_launch-3] killing on exit
Exception AttributeError: AttributeError("'_DummyThread' object has no attribute '_Thread__block'",) in <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.pyc'> ignored
[pointcloud_throttle-4] killing on exit
process[kinect_laser-5]: started with pid [9570]
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'XmlRpc::XmlRpcException'
[pointcloud_throttle-4] process has died [pid 9417, exit code 255, cmd /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/nodelet_core/nodelet/bin/nodelet load pointcloud_to_laserscan/CloudThrottle openni_manager cloud_in:=/camera/depth/points cloud_out:=cloud_throttled __name:=pointcloud_throttle __log:=/home/turtlebot/.ros/log/661c8e88-fcf9-11e1-8620-485d607f80f5/pointcloud_throttle-4.log].
log file: /home/turtlebot/.ros/log/661c8e88-fcf9-11e1-8620-485d607f80f5/pointcloud_throttle-4*.log
respawning...
[pointcloud_throttle-4] restarting process
Exception AttributeError: AttributeError("'_DummyThread' object has no attribute '_Thread__block'",) in <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.pyc'> ignored
process[pointcloud_throttle-4]: started with pid [9590]
[FATAL] [1347468671.821272043]: Service call failed!
[FATAL] [1347468671.926025778]: Service call failed!
[FATAL] [1347468671.926025149]: Service call failed!
[FATAL] [1347468671.927632950]: Service call failed!
[kinect_laser_narrow-6] process has died [pid 9446, exit code 255, cmd /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/nodelet_core/nodelet/bin/nodelet load pointcloud_to_laserscan/CloudToScan openni_manager cloud:=/cloud_throttled scan:=/narrow_scan __name:=kinect_laser_narrow __log:=/home/turtlebot/.ros/log/661c8e88-fcf9-11e1-8620-485d607f80f5/kinect_laser_narrow-6.log].
log file: /home/turtlebot/.ros/log/661c8e88-fcf9-11e1-8620-485d607f80f5/kinect_laser_narrow-6*.log
respawning...
[kinect_laser_narrow-6] restarting process
Exception AttributeError: AttributeError("'_DummyThread' object has no attribute '_Thread__block'",) in <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.pyc'> ignored
process[kinect_laser_narrow-6]: started with pid [9731]
[openni_launch-3] process has died [pid 9535, exit code 255, cmd /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/nodelet_core/nodelet/bin/nodelet load openni_camera/OpenNINodelet openni_manager __name:=openni_launch __log:=/home/turtlebot/.ros/log/661c8e88-fcf9-11e1-8620-485d607f80f5/openni_launch-3.log].
log file: /home/turtlebot/.ros/log/661c8e88-fcf9-11e1-8620-485d607f80f5/openni_launch-3*.log
respawning...
[openni_launch-3] restarting process
Exception AttributeError: AttributeError("'_DummyThread' object has no attribute '_Thread__block'",) in <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.pyc'> ignored
process[openni_launch-3]: started with pid [9752]
[pointcloud_throttle-4] process has died [pid 9590, exit code 255, cmd /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/nodelet_core/nodelet/bin/nodelet load pointcloud_to_laserscan/CloudThrottle openni_manager cloud_in:=/camera/depth/points cloud_out:=cloud_throttled __name:=pointcloud_throttle __log:=/home/turtlebot/.ros/log/661c8e88-fcf9-11e1-8620-485d607f80f5/pointcloud_throttle-4.log].
log file: /home/turtlebot/.ros/log/661c8e88-fcf9-11e1-8620-485d607f80f5/pointcloud_throttle-4*.log
respawning...
[kinect_laser-5] process has died [pid 9570, exit code 255, cmd /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/nodelet_core/nodelet/bin/nodelet load pointcloud_to_laserscan/CloudToScan openni_manager cloud:=/cloud_throttled __name:=kinect_laser __log:=/home/turtlebot/.ros/log/661c8e88-fcf9-11e1-8620-485d607f80f5/kinect_laser-5.log].
log file: /home/turtlebot/.ros/log/661c8e88-fcf9-11e1-8620-485d607f80f5/kinect_laser-5*.log
respawning...
[pointcloud_throttle-4] restarting process
Exception AttributeError: AttributeError("'_DummyThread' object has no attribute '_Thread__block'",) in <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.pyc'> ignored
process[pointcloud_throttle-4]: started with pid [9772]
[kinect_laser-5] restarting process
Exception AttributeError: AttributeError("'_DummyThread' object has no attribute '_Thread__block'",) in <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.pyc'> ignored
```

process[kinect_laser-5]: started with pid [9774]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/43723/turtlebot-navigation-error-in-fuerte-and-12.04/) by [Aroarus](https://answers.ros.org/users/990/aroarus/) on ROS Answers with karma: 122 on 2012-09-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It turns out that this was caused by leftover processes running.  Two solutions to this problem:

Reboot turtlebot and workstation, and cycle power to the create.

or

Kill all services related to the turtlebot. (especially nodelet and XnSensorServer)

Then it works fine!

---

Originally posted by [Aroarus](https://answers.ros.org/users/990/aroarus/) with karma: 122 on 2012-09-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0